# library conflict ffi ; how to resolve conflict in two different versions of the same library - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use the [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus/versions) and [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) library but they are conflicting with the internal library used by them ffi ^1.0.0. When this happens, how can I resolve it? Is it possible to import two different versions of a library? In case the [ffi ^1.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/ffi/versions)?

> [testesFlutter] flutter pub get
> Running "flutter pub get" in testesFlutter...
> Resolving dependencies...
> Because open_file >=3.1.0 depends on ffi ^1.0.0 and share_plus 6.3.1 depends on ffi ^2.0.1, open_file >=3.1.0 is incompatible with share_plus 6.3.1.
> So, because view_page_testes depends on both share_plus 6.3.1 and open_file 3.2.1, version solving failed.
> pub get failed
> command: "/Users/lucasbarreto/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example"
> pub env: {
> "FLUTTER_ROOT": "/Users/lucasbarreto/flutter",
> "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "vscode.dart-code:flutter_cli:get",
> "PUB_CACHE": "/Users/lucasbarreto/.pub-cache",
> }
> exit code: 1
> exit code 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dependency conflict in your project. In your case, you depend on `open_file` and `share_plus`. `open_file` requires  ffi version `1.0.0` and `share_plus` requires ffi version `2.0.1`. To solve this problem you can use 3 steps:

1. Either you can change the version of the dependency so that both the packages support a common `ffi` version. You can do this by either hardcoding the value or letting pub do the job by specifying any in the dependency version.

```
dependency:
  open_file: any
```

2. You can add this in your `pubspec.yaml`.

```
dependencies:
  open_file: //your version
  share_plus: //your version
dependency_overrides:
  ffi: '2.0.1' //This overrides the dependency in both packages.
```

3. You can create a fork of the project you want to upgrade the dependency of and then clone it into your git repository. Then you can change the version of the ffi the package uses. Now in your `pubspec.yaml`, you can in your `dependencies` import fork like this:

```
dependencies:
  open_file:
    git:
      url: your github package url
```

For details see: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#conflict-resolution